# Django admin list display with list of callable

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django project which create lots of reports, and each user has different permissions to view different report. And now I have a admin page which summarize all the user permissions for all reports, and I did it by sth similar to this:

```
class userAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def report1_perm(self, user):
        return user.has_perm('report1')
    def report2_perm(self, user):
        return user.has_perm('report2')
    list_display=['report1_perm', 'report2_perm']
```

Now instead of having to def a diff method for each report, I want to make callables from the list of reports I have, so sth like this

```
class userAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        def make_f(report):
            def report_perm(self, user):
                return user.has_perm(report)
            return report_perm
        list_display = []
        for report in reports:
            list_display.append(make_f(report))
        return list_display
```

However I am getting`TypeError: report_perm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'` which I do not know how to fix.
I wonder am I on the right path or there is a better solution than this

Comment: But I am not calling the report_perm(), I just make the callable and I think django calls it to determine what to show in the list

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are calling it when you do `make_f(report)`.

I guess you need to build this differently

To retain partly your structure, one solution could be to call only once with both report & user at the same time:

```
 class userAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request, user):
        def make_f(report, user):
           ...
        list_display = []
        for report in reports:
            list_display.append(make_f(report, user))
        return list_display
```

Comment: The problem here is `def get_list_display(self, request)` is a django admin function I am trying to orverride, so I can not pass user to it.

Comment: You then need to define within 'userAdmin' a function that enables you  to retrieve `user` from somewhere (a `get_reporting_user function`), and then within the custom `get_list_display` function, you can call the newly created `get_reporting_user ` function to retrieve `user`